# Output not displayed with usleep until a line break is given

Tags: c, terminal, output, putchar

I'm trying to program a simple "typewriter" effect in C, where text appears one letter at a time with a delay. Here's the function I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void typestring(const char *str, useconds_t delay)
{
    while (*str) {
        putchar(*(str++));
        usleep(delay);
    }
}
```

The problem is the text doesn't actually appear until a `\n` is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have been cautioned so many times against the fflush() thingie, especially fflush(stdin) that I have quitted using fflush() altogether.

Comment: Can anyone give an alternative solution to this typewriter problem without using fflush()?

Comment: I don't know if possible in Windows, but in Linux you can use `<termios.h>` and set the terminal to non-buffering. Look at the link in my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output to `stdout` is buffered. Using `\n` you are forcing a flush. If you want to change this, you will need to change the settings of the terminal (for Linux look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios)) or use

```
void typestring(const char *str, useconds_t delay)
{
    while (*str) {
        putchar(*(str++));
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `stdout`? Anyways, once I made that change, it worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should flush `stdout` not `stdin`.

Comment: Not sure, but the wise ones here have cautioned me many times against using fflush(stdin).

Answer (score 2):

Your output stream might have get buffered, `'\n'` flushes the buffer.

Try `fflush(stdout` after `putchar()`, as

```
while (*str) {
        putchar(*(str++));
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(delay);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` implicitly forces output device to flush buffered input. To flush you should explicitly use [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush):

```
 fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Output Stream is buffered that's why text doesn't actually appear until a \n is displayed
'\n' flushes the output stream (hard flush) to do manually the same you can call 
 this function [**fflush(stdout)**].

```
while (*str) {
        putchar(*(str++));
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(delay);
    }
```

or you can use

```
while (*str) {
            printf("%c\n",*(str++));
            usleep(delay);
        }
```