# SLEEP: (Sleep or usleep) is not suspending everything in my thread in Linux but it does in Windows? why?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sleep, usleep

In Windows:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      Sleep(100);    // Sleep 100 ms in Windows
      printf(".[%d] ", i);
    }
```

The result is a bracketed number comes out every 100ms in Windows.

In Linux:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      usleep(100000);    // Sleep 100 ms in Linux 
      printf(".[%d] ", i);
    }
```

The result is a GROUP ob bracketed number comes out every 100ms in Linux.  It is running the loop, just not printing out the numbers until sleep is done.  ????

Comment: Try sleep command on Windows from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17283549/5517378). Maybe your sleep comand in Windows doesn't interpret 100 as milliseconds but rather as a seconds.

Comment: I'd say the printf on Linux is getting buffered, so it only prints once that buffer is filled up, you can test by calling fflush(stdout); after the printf

You could also disable buffering beforehand with setbuf(stdout, NULL);

Comment: My guess would be you need to flush - `fflush(stdout);`  (And by the way, `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{100});` should be more portable.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf() not print anything before sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/338273/608639), [C sleep function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13568388/608639), [Printf in C with using sleep not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27077505/608639), [C sleep method obstructs output to console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28351161/608639), [Output not displayed with usleep until a line break is given](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16142384/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is buffered. You don't see the dots, but they are issued like clockwork.

If you add

```
fflush(stdout);
```

or a newline to the output string, you should see the dots appear regularly.